# Oracle hint ORDERED not working. How to force JOIN order?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I have a store procedure that use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` two tables by id to get some value, then `LEFT JOIN` other tables to get more information.

The problem is that I think optimizer dont use `FULL OUTER JOIN` first, so it can't get the id to `LEFT JOIN` other tables, but it didn't show any errors, instead it get all the NULL value for those "more information".

If I insert the value of the `FULL OUTER JOIN` to a GTT table, then user that GTT table to `LEFT JOIN` with those others table then it return all the correct information.

I try using the hint `/*+ORDERED */` => NULL information again. Use `/*+ LEADING(t1 t2) */`  => NULL information too.

I use CTE to nest the `FULL OUTER JOIN`, then use CTE to `LEFT JOIN` => NULL information too.

I change to database 12c and run procedure, no need hint => correct information.

So how could I do now? Use a GTT, and split one query to two?

This is example for my case, only for describe because with this query it get **correct information** but in my procedure with real table it get **NULL information**

```
WITH t1 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 3 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS id, 9 AS value FROM dual 
)
, t2 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 8 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, 2 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS id, 1 AS value FROM dual 
)
, t3 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'ab1' AS name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 'sb2' AS name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, 'tb3' AS name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS id, 'cs5' AS name FROM dual 
)
SELECT /*+ORDERED */
    NVL(t1.id, t2.id) AS id,
    t3.name, --In real case, this column return all NULL value
    NVL(t1.value, 0) AS value1,
    NVL(t2.value, 0) AS value2
FROM t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 
ON t3.id = NVL(t1.id, t2.id)
;
```

.

.

.

**For more/ detail information**, This is the real query, I copy from my procedure and set value for parameter to run and get `NULL information`

```
WITH ton_dk AS
(
    SELECT sc.ma_dvi, sc.kho, sc.nhom, sc.ma_vt,
        SUM(sc.l_t) AS l_t
    FROM vt_sc sc
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ma_dvi, kho, nhom, ma_vt, nuoc, model, dv, cl, dai, rong, cao,
            MAX(ngay_ht) AS ngay_ht
        FROM vt_sc
        WHERE
            ma_dvi IN (SELECT ma_dvi FROM temp_ma_dvi WHERE ma_ct = '1')
            AND kho IN (SELECT c1 FROM temp_7)
            AND nhom LIKE '%'
            AND ma_vt LIKE '%'
            AND ngay_ht <= 20180101
            GROUP BY ma_dvi, kho, nhom, ma_vt, nuoc, model, dv, cl, dai, rong, cao
    ) m
    ON sc.ma_dvi = m.ma_dvi
        AND sc.kho = m.kho AND sc.nhom = m.nhom
        AND sc.ma_vt = m.ma_vt AND sc.nuoc = m.nuoc
        AND sc.model = m.model AND sc.dv = m.dv AND sc.cl = m.cl
        AND sc.dai = m.dai AND sc.rong = m.rong AND sc.cao = m.cao
        AND sc.ngay_ht = m.ngay_ht
    GROUP BY sc.ma_dvi, sc.kho, sc.nhom, sc.ma_vt
    HAVING SUM(sc.l_t) <> 0
)
, ton_ck AS
(
    SELECT sc.ma_dvi, sc.kho, sc.nhom, sc.ma_vt,
        SUM(sc.l_t) AS l_t
    FROM vt_sc sc
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ma_dvi, kho, nhom, ma_vt, nuoc, model, dv, cl, dai, rong, cao,
            MAX(ngay_ht) AS ngay_ht
        FROM vt_sc
        WHERE
            ma_dvi IN (SELECT ma_dvi FROM temp_ma_dvi WHERE ma_ct = '1')
            AND kho IN (SELECT c1 FROM temp_7)
            AND nhom LIKE '%'
            AND ma_vt LIKE '%'
            AND ngay_ht <= 20181130
            GROUP BY ma_dvi, kho, nhom, ma_vt, nuoc, model, dv, cl, dai, rong, cao
    ) m
    ON sc.ma_dvi = m.ma_dvi
        AND sc.kho = m.kho AND sc.nhom = m.nhom
        AND sc.ma_vt = m.ma_vt AND sc.nuoc = m.nuoc
        AND sc.model = m.model AND sc.dv = m.dv AND sc.cl = m.cl
        AND sc.dai = m.dai AND sc.rong = m.rong AND sc.cao = m.cao
        AND sc.ngay_ht = m.ngay_ht
    GROUP BY sc.ma_dvi, sc.kho, sc.nhom, sc.ma_vt
    HAVING SUM(sc.l_t) <> 0
)
SELECT /*+ORDERED */
    NVL(d.ma_dvi, c.ma_dvi) AS ma_dvi,
    NVL(d.ma_vt, c.ma_vt) AS ma_vt,
    m.ten AS ten_vt,
    m.dvi,
    m.du_tru,
    NVL(d.kho, c.kho) AS kho,
    k.ten AS ten_kho,
    k.ma_tk AS tk_kho,
    k.dvi_ql AS dvi_ql,
    NVL(d.l_t, 0) AS l_ton_dk,
    NVL(c.l_t, 0) AS l_ton_ck
FROM ton_dk d
FULL OUTER JOIN ton_ck c
ON d.ma_dvi = c.ma_dvi
    AND d.kho = c.kho AND d.nhom = c.nhom
    AND d.ma_vt = c.ma_vt
LEFT JOIN vt_ma_vt m
ON NVL(d.nhom, c.nhom) = m.nhom
    AND NVL(d.ma_vt, c.ma_vt) = m.ma
    AND m.ma_dvi = NVL(d.ma_dvi, c.ma_dvi)
LEFT JOIN vt_ma_kho k
ON NVL(d.kho, c.kho) = k.ma 
    AND k.ma_dvi = NVL(d.ma_dvi, c.ma_dvi)
ORDER BY 1, 5, 8;
```

Result:

```
ma_dvi  ma_vt           ten_vt  dvi     du_tru      kho         ten_kho     tk_kho  dvi_ql  l_ton_dk l_ton_ck                            
010     V.ON61.                                     10-09V                                  0               161.5
010     13.01.01.121                                07-1.3                                  0               1    
010     19.03.022                                   07-3.3                                  0               16   
010     V.DNP15.1                                   05-032(KD)                              0               7
```

Explain plan:

```
Plan hash value: 1068421260                                                                                 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
| Id  | Operation                      | Name        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |             |     1 |   309 |       | 10587   (1)| 00:02:08 |      
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                 |             |     1 |   309 |       | 10587   (1)| 00:02:08 |      
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |             |     1 |   309 |       | 10586   (1)| 00:02:08 |      
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |             |     1 |   229 |       | 10585   (1)| 00:02:08 |      
|   4 |     VIEW                       | VW_FOJ_0    |     1 |   143 |       | 10583   (1)| 00:02:07 |      
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN FULL OUTER      |             |     1 |   182 |       | 10583   (1)| 00:02:07 |      
|   6 |       VIEW                     |             |     1 |    91 |       |  5200   (1)| 00:01:03 |      
|*  7 |        FILTER                  |             |       |       |       |            |          |      
|   8 |         HASH GROUP BY          |             |     1 |   149 |       |  5200   (1)| 00:01:03 |      
|*  9 |          HASH JOIN             |             |     4 |   596 |       |  5199   (1)| 00:01:03 |      
|  10 |           VIEW                 |             | 19105 |  1417K|       |  2631   (1)| 00:00:32 |      
|  11 |            HASH GROUP BY       |             | 19105 |    10M|    11M|  2631   (1)| 00:00:32 |      
|* 12 |             HASH JOIN          |             | 19105 |    10M|       |   248   (1)| 00:00:03 |      
|  13 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL | TEMP_7      |   353 |   173K|       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
|  14 |              NESTED LOOPS      |             | 19105 |  1641K|       |   246   (1)| 00:00:03 |      
|* 15 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEMP_MA_DVI |     1 |    19 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
|* 16 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN | VT_SC_P     | 19105 |  1287K|       |   244   (1)| 00:00:03 |      
|  17 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL    | VT_SC       |   743K|    51M|       |  2562   (2)| 00:00:31 |      
|  18 |       VIEW                     |             |     1 |    91 |       |  5383   (1)| 00:01:05 |      
|* 19 |        FILTER                  |             |       |       |       |            |          |      
|  20 |         HASH GROUP BY          |             |     1 |   149 |       |  5383   (1)| 00:01:05 |      
|* 21 |          HASH JOIN             |             |     5 |   745 |       |  5382   (1)| 00:01:05 |      
|  22 |           VIEW                 |             | 20568 |  1526K|       |  2813   (1)| 00:00:34 |      
|  23 |            HASH GROUP BY       |             | 20568 |    11M|    12M|  2813   (1)| 00:00:34 |      
|* 24 |             HASH JOIN          |             | 20568 |    11M|       |   248   (1)| 00:00:03 |      
|  25 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL | TEMP_7      |   353 |   173K|       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
|  26 |              NESTED LOOPS      |             | 20568 |  1767K|       |   246   (1)| 00:00:03 |      
|* 27 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEMP_MA_DVI |     1 |    19 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
|* 28 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN | VT_SC_P     | 20568 |  1385K|       |   244   (1)| 00:00:03 |      
|  29 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL    | VT_SC       |   743K|    51M|       |  2562   (2)| 00:00:31 |      
|  30 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| VT_MA_VT    |     1 |    86 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
|* 31 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | VT_MA_VT_P  |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
|  32 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | VT_MA_KHO   |     1 |    80 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
|* 33 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | VT_MA_KHO_P |     1 |       |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                         
---------------------------------------------------                                                         

   5 - access("D"."MA_DVI"="C"."MA_DVI" AND "D"."KHO"="C"."KHO" AND "D"."NHOM"="C"."NHOM" AND               
              "D"."MA_VT"="C"."MA_VT")                                                                      
   7 - filter(SUM("SC"."L_T")<>0)                                                                           
   9 - access("SC"."MA_DVI"="M"."MA_DVI" AND "SC"."KHO"="M"."KHO" AND "SC"."NHOM"="M"."NHOM"                
              AND "SC"."MA_VT"="M"."MA_VT" AND "SC"."NUOC"="M"."NUOC" AND "SC"."MODEL"="M"."MODEL" AND      
              "SC"."DV"="M"."DV" AND "SC"."CL"="M"."CL" AND "SC"."DAI"="M"."DAI" AND "SC"."RONG"="M"."RONG" 
              AND "SC"."CAO"="M"."CAO" AND "SC"."NGAY_HT"="M"."NGAY_HT")                                    
  12 - access("C1"=SYS_OP_C2C("KHO"))                                                                       
  15 - filter("MA_CT"='1')                                                                                  
  16 - access("MA_DVI"="MA_DVI" AND "NGAY_HT"<=20180101)                                                    
       filter("NGAY_HT"<=20180101 AND "NHOM" LIKE '%' AND "MA_VT" LIKE '%')                                 
  19 - filter(SUM("SC"."L_T")<>0)                                                                           
  21 - access("SC"."MA_DVI"="M"."MA_DVI" AND "SC"."KHO"="M"."KHO" AND "SC"."NHOM"="M"."NHOM"                
              AND "SC"."MA_VT"="M"."MA_VT" AND "SC"."NUOC"="M"."NUOC" AND "SC"."MODEL"="M"."MODEL" AND      
              "SC"."DV"="M"."DV" AND "SC"."CL"="M"."CL" AND "SC"."DAI"="M"."DAI" AND "SC"."RONG"="M"."RONG" 
              AND "SC"."CAO"="M"."CAO" AND "SC"."NGAY_HT"="M"."NGAY_HT")                                    
  24 - access("C1"=SYS_OP_C2C("KHO"))                                                                       
  27 - filter("MA_CT"='1')                                                                                  
  28 - access("MA_DVI"="MA_DVI" AND "NGAY_HT"<=20181130)                                                    
       filter("NGAY_HT"<=20181130 AND "NHOM" LIKE '%' AND "MA_VT" LIKE '%')                                 
  31 - access("M"."MA_DVI"(+)="D"."MA_DVI" AND "M"."NHOM"(+)="D"."NHOM" AND                                 
              "M"."MA"(+)="D"."MA_VT")                                                                      
  33 - access("K"."MA_DVI"(+)="from$_subquery$_015"."QCSJ_C000000001500000" AND                             
              "K"."MA"(+)="from$_subquery$_015"."QCSJ_C000000001500002")                                    

Note                                                                                                        
-----                                                                                                       
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Comment: Hi Pham, we often see you on the site, but I would ask that you try to post a more minimal question.  Most users won't have the bandwidth to digest all this information (not that information is inherently bad...but too much of it can be).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you have suggestion? I'm confusing on this problem, because the example I post have correct result, but the real query got the wrong one. May be the optimizer or something else, so I don't know which information should be omitted/ skipped...

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Performance? If you want to evaluate CTE tables aside you need MATERIALIZE hint.

Comment: @ibre5041 I want to get the correct result, for e.g in my sample query, I want the column `name` is NOT NULL in result.

Comment: The change of exec plan can not influence the query result. Either u face Oracle bug or your assumption is wrong. In your cause t3.name might be understood as being beyond LEFT OUTER JOIN to t2. I'm not sure. On 12.2 version your query return non-null values for the column NAME.

Answer (score 0):

Enforce the wanted relationships using another CTE

```
WITH t1 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 3 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS id, 9 AS value FROM dual 
)
, t2 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 8 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, 2 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS id, 1 AS value FROM dual 
)
, t3 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'ab1' AS name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 'sb2' AS name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, 'tb3' AS name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS id, 'cs5' AS name FROM dual 
)
, t4 as (
    select
         NVL(t1.id, t2.id) AS id
       , NVL(t1.value, 0) AS value1
       , NVL(t2.value, 0) AS value2
    FROM t1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    )
SELECT
      t4.id
    , t3.name
    , t4.value1
    , t4.value2
FROM t4
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t4.id
```

result:

```
+---+----+------+--------+--------+
|   | ID | NAME | VALUE1 | VALUE2 |
+---+----+------+--------+--------+
| 1 |  1 | ab1  |      2 |      8 |
| 2 |  2 | sb2  |      3 |      0 |
| 3 |  3 | tb3  |      0 |      2 |
| 4 |  5 | cs5  |      9 |      1 |
+---+----+------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried CTE before but no luck. I think it has some error with my database optimizer, because it run ok with database version 12c, and if I change the order of join manually it will raise error like `NVL(t1.id, t2.id)` can not evaluated...